# Custom Meta atribute in hibernate xml?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, spring-mvc-test

What is the purpose of custom meta tags? I have seen them at class level and at property level.

```
Example of Propery level level:
</property>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string">
      <meta attribute="Test"/>
    </property>

Example of class level
<class name="mypackage.user" table="user">
    <meta attribute="Test"/>
......
....
</class>
```

How does hibernate use this custom values in meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate, custom meta tags used while generating Java POJOs from hbm config file.
Refer https://docs.jboss.org/tools/archive/3.0.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html. Note that there is a list of Supported meta tags.

Comment: i understand  meta attribute tags like "implements" etc. Specifically wana know the non standard meta attribute tags like "Test" as mentioned above?How are these useful?